# Changing factor levels with dplyr mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably simple and I feel stupid for asking. I want to change the levels of a factor in a data frame, using mutate. Simple example:

```
library("dplyr")
dat <- data.frame(x = factor("A"), y = 1)
mutate(dat,levels(x) = "B")
```

I get:

```
Error: Unexpected '=' in "mutate(dat,levels(x) ="
```

Why is this not working? How can I change factor levels with mutate?

Comment: Perhaps `dat %>% mutate(x=factor(x, labels='B'))`  BTW, the pipe operator is not correct in your code

Comment: So, I can't use levels() in mutate? I need to explicitly encode the variable as a factor again? Hmm... (%<>% should be okay, it pipes and assigns the dat)

Comment: Yes, I want to mutate x. I thought "levels(x)" would be enough for mutate to figure out that I want to mutate x. I guess that's a design choice, as it works that way with "within".

Comment: It may be possible using `magrittr` or other packages, but why do you need to go through this route.  It is very easy to do `levels(dat$x) <- 'B'`

Comment: Wouldn't this do more than change the levels of the factor. It actually changes the values of the factor itself. That seems dangerous and leads to some odd behavior. `dat <- data.frame(x = factor(c('A', 'B', 'A')), y = c(1:3));
levels(dat$x) <- c('b', 'a', 'b');
dat`

Comment: If you must use `levels`, you can do `mutate(dat, x = `levels<-`(x, "B"))`.

Answer (score 81):

With the [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/) package from the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) this is easy, too.

```
mutate(dat, x = fct_recode(x, "B" = "A"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide the vector of the new levels ?

Comment: Yes it is:

x <- factor(c("apple", "bear", "banana", "dear")); 
fct_recode(x, !!!c(fruit = "apple", fruit = "banana"))

Answer (score 55):

I'm not quite sure I understand your question properly, but if you want to change the factor levels of `cyl` with `mutate()` you could do:

```
df <- mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 6, 8)))
```

You would get:

```
#> str(df$cyl)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "4","6","8": 2 2 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 2 ...
```

Comment: If the levels do not match the original values, instead of `factor(cyl, levels = ...)`, you should do `factor(cyl, labels = ...)`.E.g. `factor(cyl, labels = c('four', 'six', 'eight')`.

Comment: This example is not clear because `cyl` is the same afterwards

Answer (score 23):

Maybe you are looking for this plyr::revalue function:

```
mutate(dat, x = revalue(x, c("A" = "B")))
```

You can see plyr::mapvalues too.

Comment: Loading both `dplyr` and `plyr` is not working for me. The respective functions stomp over one another.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer `dplyr` and `plyr` are known to have namespacing conflicts, but `plyr` has been deprecated for some time anyway

Answer (score 22):

You can use the `recode` function from `dplyr`.

```
df <- iris %>%
     mutate(Species = recode(Species, setosa = "SETOSA",
         versicolor = "VERSICOLOR",
         virginica = "VIRGINICA"
     )
)
```

Comment: Note that recode only works on vectors, see answer from PaulFrater for a version that works.

Comment: Which answer are you referring to?

Answer (score 19):

From my understanding, the currently accepted answer only changes the order of the factor *levels*, not the actual *labels* (i.e., how the levels of the factor are called). To illustrate the difference between *levels* and *labels*, consider the following example:

Turn `cyl` into factor (specifying levels would not be necessary as they are coded in alphanumeric order):

```
    mtcars2 <- mtcars %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4, 6, 8))) 
    mtcars2$cyl[1:5]
    #[1] 6 6 4 6 8
    #Levels: 4 6 8
```

Change the order of **levels** (but not the labels itself: cyl is still the same column)

```
    mtcars3 <- mtcars2 %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(8, 6, 4))) 
    mtcars3$cyl[1:5]
    #[1] 6 6 4 6 8
    #Levels: 8 6 4
    all(mtcars3$cyl==mtcars2$cyl)
    #[1] TRUE
```

Assign new **labels** to `cyl`  The order of the labels was: c(8, 6, 4), hence we specify new labels as follows:

```
    mtcars4 <- mtcars3 %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, labels = c("new_value_for_8", 
                                                               "new_value_for_6", 
                                                               "new_value_for_4" )))
    mtcars4$cyl[1:5]
    #[1] new_value_for_6 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_4 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_8
    #Levels: new_value_for_8 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_4
```

Note how this column differs from our first columns:

```
    all(as.character(mtcars4$cyl)!=mtcars3$cyl) 
    #[1] TRUE 
    #Note: TRUE here indicates that all values are unequal because I used != instead of ==
    #as.character() was required as the levels were numeric and thus not comparable to a character vector
```

---

More details:

If we were to change the levels of `cyl` using `mtcars2` instead of `mtcars3`, we would need to specify the labels differently to get the same result. The order of labels for `mtcars2` was: c(4, 6, 8), hence we specify new labels as follows

```
    #change labels of mtcars2 (order used to be: c(4, 6, 8)
    mtcars5 <- mtcars2 %>% mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, labels = c("new_value_for_4", 
                                                               "new_value_for_6", 
                                                               "new_value_for_8" )))
```

Unlike `mtcars3$cyl` and `mtcars4$cyl`, the *labels* of `mtcars4$cyl` and `mtcars5$cyl` are thus identical, even though their *levels* have a different order.

```
    mtcars4$cyl[1:5]
    #[1] new_value_for_6 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_4 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_8
    #Levels: new_value_for_8 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_4

    mtcars5$cyl[1:5]
    #[1] new_value_for_6 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_4 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_8
    #Levels: new_value_for_4 new_value_for_6 new_value_for_8

    all(mtcars4$cyl==mtcars5$cyl)
    #[1] TRUE

    levels(mtcars4$cyl) == levels(mtcars5$cyl)
    #1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 18):

Can't comment because I don't have enough reputation points, but recode only works on a vector, so the above code in @Stefano's answer should be

```
df <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = recode(Species, 
     setosa = "SETOSA",
     versicolor = "VERSICOLOR",
     virginica = "VIRGINICA")
  )
```