# Rename factor levels in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I have this data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("gravel", "sandstone", "siltstone"))
```

I want to rename the levels of the variable x by adding "`R1_`" before the name of the levels. I can do it following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39634235/5420677).

```
df %>%  dplyr::mutate(x = fct_recode(x, 
                                     "R1_gravel" = "gravel", 
                                     "R1_sandstone" = "sandstone",
                                     "R1_siltstone" = "siltstone" 
                                     ))

             x
1    R1_gravel
2 R1_sandstone
3 R1_siltstone
```

However, in my actual data.frame, variable x has many levels. So, it is time taking to rename all the levels as above. I wonder if there is a faster way to 
 rename all the levels through adding R1_ at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
levels(df$x) <- paste0("R1_",levels(df$x))
# df
# x
# 1    R1_gravel
# 2 R1_sandstone
# 3 R1_siltstone
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and help