# Pipes, convert numeric to factor with unobserved levels retained

Tags: r, dplyr, numeric, magrittr

In `mtcars$gear`, the only numbers observed are 3, 4, and 5. I want to convert this to a factor in which:

- "China" = 1
- "France" = 2
- "Russia" = 3
- "UK" = 4
- "USA" = 5

I want to then plot this so that we see that "China" and "France" have 0 values.

I want to do everything through pipes.

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = factor(gear, labels = list("China" = 1, "France" = 2, "Russia" = 3, "UK" = 4, "USA" = 5))) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarize(Count = n()) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x = gear, y = Count))

"Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
   Evaluation error: invalid 'labels'; length 5 should be 1 or 3."
```

This is similar to [Changing factor levels with dplyr mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190435/changing-factor-levels-with-dplyr-mutate) except I want to include **unobserved** values.

Comment: I think you want `levels = 1:5,labels = c("China","France","Russia","UK","USA")` and then you'll want the very latest version of **dplyr** and use the `.drop` argument in `group_by()`.

Comment: In addition, you can use `geom_bar` instead and then there would be no need for `group_by(gear) %>% ... ` After `mutate` your code would be `%>% ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x = gear)) + scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1):

Proper use of levels and labels while ensuring that unobserved values are not dropped solves the issue. All credit: @joran and @markus

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = factor(gear, levels = 1:5, labels = c("China","France","Russia","UK","USA"))) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x = gear)) +
  scale_x_discrete(drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: This may solve the problem, but it enforces a disconnect between the levels and labels. Retaining the explicit assignment of the label "China" to level "1" etc. would make errors less likely - is there a solution facilitates this even with unlabelled levels??