# How to change factor values

Tags: r

My data frame has 3 factor variables and their values are:

```
"It was less than adequate for household needs", 
"It was just adequate for household needs", 
"It was more than adequate for household needs"
```

and I need them to be "1", "2", and "3".

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/29711067/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38621334/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/28190435/5325862

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
df <- data.frame(col=c("It was less than adequate for household needs", 
                       "It was just adequate for household needs",
                       "It was more than adequate for household needs"))

# suggested by @akrun (maintains the order)
df$col <- as.integer(factor(df$col, levels = unique(df$col)))

  col
1   1
2   2
3   3
```

If you want to maintain a sequential order, may be just add a new column with sequences:

```
df$code <- seq(nrow(df))

                                            col code
1 It was less than adequate for household needs    1
2      It was just adequate for household needs    2
3 It was more than adequate for household needs    3
```

Comment: Or use `as.integer(factor(df$col, levels = unique(df$col)))`

Answer (score -2):

Using the data frame from @YOLO's answer:

```
> df$col <- factor(df$col, levels = levels(df$col), labels = 1:3)
> df
  col
1   2
2   1
3   3
```